# Deformations of Pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme over $\operatorname{Spec}k$ with a universal deformation $Z$ over a smooth base scheme $T$.

Is $Z \times_T (T \times S)$ with base scheme $T \times S$ the universal deformation of the pullback $X \times_k S$ of $X$ by the map $S \to \operatorname{Spec} k$?

Comment: I guess not because infinitesmal schemes over $T\times S$ need not come from ones over $T$ but I don't know a counter example.

Comment: Take $X=S$? Then a positive answer to your question would entail that $T\times X$ is the local moduli space of $X\times X$, right? This is not reasonable (take $X$ a higher genus curve for example, as then $X\times X$ has local moduli space $T\times T$)

Comment: That is a good point, it seems like one needs to take into account deformations of the base $S$. Do you think a positive answer could be achieved in the case that the base $S$ is rigid?